# when I select tableview row that time scrollview is open so how do I get what is index no. of tableview and what is position of scrollview

Tags: ios, iphone, uiscrollview, delegates, stack-overflow

when I select tableview row that time scrollview is open so how can i get the index no. of tableview and what is position of scrollview 
my code is

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView SelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    AppDelegate *objAppdelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    if (objAppdelegate.isLegalUpdate_Event_CA==1){
        UIWebView *webvews=[[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(scrolvew.frame.size.width * i, 50, 320, scrolvew.frame.size.height-50)];
        webvews.delegate=self;
        [webvews loadHTMLString:ObjtpostAll.post_content baseURL:nil];
        //webvews.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
        webvews.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
        [scrolvew addSubview:webvews];
        [webvews release];
}
   scrolvew.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrolvew.frame.size.width * [pullRefereshTableViewController.arrData count], scrolvew.frame.size.height);
    [scrolvew setContentOffset:CGPointMake(indexPath*320, 0)];
```

Comment: Are you really trying to override `selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:`?

Answer (score 0):

```
CGFloat xOffset = _yourScrollView.contentOffset.x;
CGFloat yOffset = _yourScrollView.contentOffset.y;
```